# Push Notification in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Hi I want to have push notification in blackberry.I have already googled for the answer and got the Push Services Guide.i read this guide .This guide does not give any code information for the client side application.It talks push server sdk and its installation but does not give any idea of how to write client code to have push notification. So is there any sample code that provides the concept of push notification.

thanks

Comment: have you tried urban airship for push notification in blackberry

Comment: yes i have seen urban airship.It does not provides this service freely

Comment: For  client side code sample  refer http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client side code, refer this link [Blackberry push](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857).

Use this as server side code -

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// APP ID provided by RIM
$appid = '';
// Password provided by RIM
$password = '';

//Deliver before timestamp
$deliverbefore = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+15 minutes'));

//An array of address must be in PIN format or "push_all"
$addresstosendto[] = 'push_all';

$addresses = '';
foreach ($addresstosendto as $value) {
$addresses .= '<address address-value="' . $value . '"/>';
}

// create a new cURL resource
$err = false;
$ch = curl_init();
$messageid = microtime(true);

$data = '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm'. "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n\r\n" .
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.1//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/pap_2.1.dtd">
<pap>
<push-message push-id="' . $messageid . '" deliver-before-timestamp="' . $deliverbefore . '" source-reference="' . $appid . '">'
. $addresses .
'<quality-of-service delivery-method="confirmed"/>
</push-message>
</pap>' . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm' . "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: text/plain' . "\r\n" .
'Push-Message-ID: ' . $messageid . "\r\n\r\n" .
stripslashes('This is my message') . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm--' . "\n\r";

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Hallgren Networks BB Push Server/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $appid . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm; type=application/xml", "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", "Connection: keep-alive"));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo $xmldata = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

//Start parsing response into XML data that we can read and output
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmldata, $vals);
$errorcode = xml_get_error_code($p);
if ($errorcode > 0) {
echo xml_error_string($errorcode);
$err = true;
}
xml_parser_free($p);

echo 'Our PUSH-ID: ' . $messageid . "<br \>\n";
if (!$err && $vals[1]['tag'] == 'PUSH-RESPONSE') {
echo 'PUSH-ID: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['PUSH-ID'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'REPLY-TIME: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['REPLY-TIME'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Response CODE: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Response DESC: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \> \n";
} else {
echo '<p>An error has occured</p>' . "\n";
echo 'Error CODE: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Error DESC: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \>\n";
}


?>
```

Comment: How can i test push notification without app_id .

Comment: you cant test push notification without app id.

Comment: After testing push notification on eval urls and requesting new appId for production . Is There a change from evaluation urls and production Urls in my code while changing from eval mode to production mode .

Comment: ya, you have to change the url.

Comment: change the eval url to the new production url.

Comment: How do i use the client side code? I can see 2 java files ok. What do i do with them? Why is not a project? I m very new to BB developing and i need to create a simple app with push enabled , so i guess this code would suffice.

Comment: Also do u have any idea , how i could do that while i am developing with phonegap/cordova? I know that theres no plugin for it to enable push notifications and that i should use native code , as it uses the WebWorks API. So can i use this code on my phonegap App ?

Comment: Hey, i used the same code, however it returns me An error has occured

Error CODE: 2000
Error DESC: 2000