# Getting started with blackberry 7 development?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Can someone please point me to the right direction on learning how to develop for blackberry 7?

Actually what i need is just to implement push notifications and open a web URL nothing more.

I see that there are different frameworks for this platform like webWorks etc etc.

I am a bit confused though.. I do not want to write Javascript or HTML or CSS.

I want to write native code that enables push and loads me an external URL which i already have.

Any tutorial on that or a bit of info would be great :)

Comment: you can get push code from http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857

Comment: any project to show how to implement these java files? I ve found them before but i am not sure how to use them if not implemented in a sample project

Comment: refer http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Push%20Notification

Comment: is this for < BB os 7.x  ??

Comment: yes, it will support 5,6,and 7 versions.

Comment: Incredible! Well if you want take your time and create an answer based on your comments , i ll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: already i posted the answer in some other questions. you can upvote it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481122/push-notification-in-blackberry/9427411#9427411

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  -

```
Client side code -

// Main Class-
class App extends UiApplication {
 private static App theApp;
  public App() {
       pushScreen(new register());    
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
          if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("BB_push") ){
             theApp = new App();
             theApp.enterEventDispatcher();   

            }
        else {      
            BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
            backApp.setupBackgroundApplication();
            backApp.enterEventDispatcher();

       }       
    }  
}




//Register Class-
public class register extends MainScreen{
    public register(){
    final ButtonField btn=new ButtonField("Register");
        add(btn);
 FieldChangeListener listener=new FieldChangeListener() {
               public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

                   if(field==btn){

                     registerBpas();

                   }

               }};
    btn.setChangeListener(listener);

}
}


public static void registerBpas() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
            final String registerUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, null) + ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
            System.out.println("\n\n\n msg registerBPAS URL is:  "+ registerUrl);
            HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(registerUrl);
            InputStream is = httpConnection.openInputStream();
            String response = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is));
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg RESPOSE CODE :    " + response);
            httpConnection.close();
            String nextUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, response) + ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg nextUrl :    " + nextUrl);
            HttpConnection nextHttpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(nextUrl);
            InputStream nextInputStream = nextHttpConnection.openInputStream();
            response = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(nextInputStream));
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg RESPOSE CODE 1:    " + response);
            nextHttpConnection.close();
            if (REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL.equals(response) || USER_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED.equals(response)) {
                Dialog.alert("msg Registered successfully for BIS push");


                System.out.println("msg Registered successfully for BIS push");
            } else {
                Dialog.alert("msg BPAS rejected registration");
                System.out.println("msg BPAS rejected registration");
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Dialog.alert("msg IOException on register() " + e + " " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("msg IOException on register() " + e + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    }.start();
}

private static String formRegisterRequest(String bpasUrl, String appId, String token) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bpasUrl);
    sb.append("/mss/PD_subReg?");
    sb.append("serviceid=").append(appId);
    sb.append("&osversion=").append(DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion());
    sb.append("&model=").append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    if (token != null && token.length() > 0) {
        sb.append("&").append(token);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}

public static void close(Connection conn, InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    if (os != null) {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

//Background listener class

class BackgroundApplication extends Application {  

    public BackgroundApplication() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void setupBackgroundApplication(){

        MessageReadingThread messageReadingThread = new MessageReadingThread();
        messageReadingThread.start();

    }  

    private static class MessageReadingThread extends Thread { private boolean running;
        private ServerSocketConnection socket;
        private HttpServerConnection conn;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private PushInputStream pushInputStream;

        public MessageReadingThread() {
            this.running = true;
        }

        public void run() {

             String url = "http://:" + Port;
             url += ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
             if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) && RadioInfo.areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
                 url += ";interface=wifi";
                 }

            try {
                socket = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open( url );
            } catch( IOException ex ) {
                // can't open the port, probably taken by another application
                onListenError( ex );
            }

            while( running ) {
                try {
                    Object o = socket.acceptAndOpen();
                    conn = (HttpServerConnection) o;
                    inputStream = conn.openInputStream();
                    pushInputStream = new MDSPushInputStream( conn, inputStream );
                    PushMessageReader.process( pushInputStream, conn );
                } catch( Exception e ) {
                    if( running ) {
                      //  Logger.warn( "Failed to read push message, caused by " + e.getMessage() );
                        running = false;
                    }
                } finally {
                   // PushUtils.close( conn, pushInputStream, null );
                }
            }

          //  Logger.log( "Stopped listening for push messages" );
        }

        public void stopRunning() {
            running = false;
            //PushUtils.close( socket, null, null );
        }

        private void onListenError( final Exception ex ) {
           // Logger.warn( "Failed to open port, caused by " + ex );
          System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

}
//push message reader class -

// HTTP header property that carries unique push message ID
    private static final String MESSAGE_ID_HEADER = "Push-Message-ID";
    // content type constant for text messages
    private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT = "text";
    private static final int MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH = 10;
    private static String[] messageIdHistory = new String[MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH];
    private static byte historyIndex;

    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[15 * 1024];
public static void process(PushInputStream pis, Connection conn) {
        System.out.println("Reading incoming push message ...");

        try {

            HttpServerConnection httpConn;
            if (conn instanceof HttpServerConnection) {
                httpConn = (HttpServerConnection) conn;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not process non-http pushes, expected HttpServerConnection but have "
                        + conn.getClass().getName());
            }

            String msgId = httpConn.getHeaderField(MESSAGE_ID_HEADER);
            String msgType = httpConn.getType();
            String encoding = httpConn.getEncoding();

            System.out.println("Message props: ID=" + msgId + ", Type=" + msgType + ", Encoding=" + encoding);


            boolean accept = true;
            if (!alreadyReceived(msgId)) {
                byte[] binaryData;

                if (msgId == null) {
                    msgId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }

                if (msgType == null) {
                    System.out.println("Message content type is NULL");
                    accept = false;
                } else if (msgType.indexOf(MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT) >= 0) {
                    // a string
                    int size = pis.read(buffer);
                    binaryData = new byte[size];
                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, binaryData, 0, size);   

                    PushMessage message = new PushMessage(msgId, System.currentTimeMillis(), binaryData, true, true );
                    String text = new String( message.getData(), "UTF-8" );
                     try{
                            final Dialog screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, " "+text,
                                    Dialog.OK,
                                    //mImageGreen.getBitmap(),
                                    null, Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
                            final UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
                            Application.getApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(0x749cb23a76c66e2dL, 0, null, null);
                                    ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 0, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);

                                }
                            });
                            screen.setDialogClosedListener(new MyDialogClosedListener());
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }


                    // TODO report message
                }  else {
                    System.out.println("Unknown message type " + msgType);
                    accept = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received duplicate message with ID " + msgId);
            }
            pis.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to process push message: " + e);
        }
    }



private static boolean alreadyReceived(String id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Arrays.contains(messageIdHistory, id)) {
            return true;
        }

        // new ID, append to the history (oldest element will be eliminated)
        messageIdHistory[historyIndex++] = id;
        if (historyIndex >= MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH) {
            historyIndex = 0;
        }
        return false;
    }



public class PushMessage{

    private String id;
    private long timestamp;
    private byte[] data;
    private boolean textMesasge;
    private boolean unread;

    public PushMessage( String id, long timestamp, byte[] data, boolean textMesasge, boolean unread ) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.data = data;
        this.textMesasge = textMesasge;
        this.unread = unread;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public boolean isTextMesasge() {
        return textMesasge;
    }

    public boolean isUnread() {
        return unread;
    }

    public void setUnread( boolean unread ) {
        this.unread = unread;
    }

}

public class MyDialogClosedListener implements DialogClosedListener
    {

    public void dialogClosed(Dialog dialog, int choice)
    {
        if(dialog.equals(dialog))
        {
           if(choice == -1)
            {
                //Your code for Press OK
            }
            if(choice == 1)
            {
                //Your code for Press Cancel

            }
                   }
   }
}


Server sode PHP code is given Below -

ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // APP ID provided by RIM
$appid = 'app id';
// Password provided by RIM
$password = 'password';
//Deliver before timestamp
$deliverbefore = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+time minutes'));

//An array of address must be in PIN format or "push_all"
$addresstosendto[] = 'your pin';

$addresses = '';
foreach ($addresstosendto as $value) {
$addresses .= '
';
}

// create a new cURL resource
$err = false;
$ch = curl_init();
$messageid = microtime(true);

$data = '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm'. "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n\r\n" .
'


'
. $addresses .
'
' . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm' . "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: text/plain' . "\r\n" .
'Push-Message-ID: ' . $messageid . "\r\n\r\n" .
stripslashes('r') . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm--' . "\n\r";

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest");//"https://cp2991.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Hallgren Networks BB Push Server/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $appid . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm; type=application/xml", "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", "Connection: keep-alive"));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo $xmldata = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

//Start parsing response into XML data that we can read and output
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmldata, $vals);
$errorcode = xml_get_error_code($p);
if ($errorcode > 0) {
echo xml_error_string($errorcode);
$err = true;
}
xml_parser_free($p);

echo 'Our PUSH-ID: ' . $messageid . "
\n";
if (!$err && $vals[1]['tag'] == 'PUSH-RESPONSE') {
echo 'PUSH-ID: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['PUSH-ID'] . "
\n";
echo 'REPLY-TIME: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['REPLY-TIME'] . "
\n";
echo 'Response CODE: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['CODE'] . "
\n";
echo 'Response DESC: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['DESC'] . "
\n";
} else {
echo 'An error has occured
' . "\n";
echo 'Error CODE: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['CODE'] . "
\n";
echo 'Error DESC: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['DESC'] . "
\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you give me some info on how exactly to use at least the client side code in order to run? I mean if i take it all and place it in my main.java i get errors. If i try to put every class in a different .java file again i get errors. How do i implement this in a fresh new blackberry project?

Comment: when i put it all together?

Comment: There are 89 errors.. Every 2 lines there is an error. I am sure i dont do something correctly.. Are you sure i just need to copy paste all the client code in the single main.java file ?

Comment: UIApplication class and MainScreen classes are given

Comment: I am really sorry but i dont understand what do you mean. I am an iOS developer and i ve never used eclipse nor java before. What do you mean the classes are given? Would it be easier if you could tell me what part of code goes inside what class? Or even better post a sample project with this functionality?

Comment: getting this erros when running server script: Invalid document endOur PUSH-ID: 1363976072.1667 An error has occured 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\BlackBerryServer\SendingPush.php on line 83
Error CODE: 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\BlackBerryServer\SendingPush.php on line 85
Error DESC:

Comment: @donparalias you add id and password ?

Comment: Yes but just those 2.. Shall i put an address or a date for the "deliveryBefore" or smth else?