# Do we have a token in BlackBerry push?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, push

I am trying to develop an application for OS < 7.X that implements push notifications.

I finally made it make the client/server samples to work. However , i dont understand at all how the push works. In the server sample , the only thing that i specify are the username/password credentials provided by RIM and then the device_id and something called push_id(which can be any string as i already tested).

So where is the token provided by the server? We dont need a token to send a push in BB ? And if not , what do i keep on my server?

Does the device_id work as a "token" that we used in iOS , WP7 and Android? I am pretty sure i am missing something here , because this looks really odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending push notifications, you don't need any tokens. The devise `PIN` number is enough for sending push messages. Only keep the PIN number.
For server side code refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481122/push-notification-in-blackberry/9427411#9427411)